# WSARecv() receives less bytes than sent

Tags: c++, winsock2

I'm trying to send an image through WinSock. I'm reading the image in blocks of fixed size. The WSASend() sends the right amount of information, but when i'm receiving it, i'm having smaller pieces than the regular blocks.

```
char* TCPClient::ReadSocket()
{
    Flags = 0;
    if ((WSARecv(Info->GetSocket(), &(Info->GetWSABufForRead()), 1, &RecvBytes, &Flags, NULL, NULL)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
            sprintf(exceptBuf, "WSARecv() failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            throw new CException(exceptBuf);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("WSARecv() is OK!\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        if (RecvBytes == 0) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        Info->SetRecvBytes(RecvBytes);
        return Info->ReadBuffer();
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

EDIT: What I actually want to know is how to get the entire block of information.

Comment: Correct. It can. Where does it say it can't?

Comment: Yes. You need to understand how TCP works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the post doesn't actually have a question.

Comment: You need to loop until you get whatever you need.

Comment: And what should be the condition for ending the loop? I was trying to implement a loop function on the WSARecv function, but it just freezes at the second call of the loop. My condition was: while (block_size > 0) { //... 
block_size = block_size - RecvBytes; }

Comment: Recognizing the end of the message is the termination condition. What that means depends entirely on your application protocol and cannot be answered in general terms.

Comment: Simplest way is to length prefix your message and on the receive side read the message length and loop to read the rest of the message.

Comment: If you know the block size up-front just call WSARecv in a loop untill you know you read the whole block. You get the read size in out paramter. In your case it's RecvBytes. If you don't know the chunk size (and probably it will be the case when you are about to send the last part of the image) you should prefix your data with a header indicating how many bytes are you actually sending. Then read the header first and proceed with reading rest of the data.